# INSERT Record in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have six tables in my database; their schema is as follows:

1) postad

```
userid  varchar(20) 
cityid  varchar(20) 
Ucategory_id    varchar(20) 
ad_id   varchar(20) 
title   varchar(MAX)    
ad_description  varchar(MAX)    
img_id  int username    varchar(20) 
 video  varchar(MAX)    
subcategory_id  varchar(50) 
date_creation   datetime    
postid  int
```

2) user details

```
userpwd varchar(20) 
emailid varchar(30)
mobile  numeric(10, 0)  
squestion   varchar(MAX)    
sanswer varchar(MAX)    
gender  varchar(20)
status_user varchar(20)
```

3)sub category

```
subact_id   varchar(50) 
category_id varchar(20) 
subcat_name varchar(50)
```

4) imagegallery

```
img_id  int Unchecked
image_size  bigint  
image_content   image
```

5) Adtype

```
adid    varchar(20) 
adtype  varchar(20)
```

6) category

```
cat_id  varchar(20) 
cat_name    char(150)
```

I want to insert a record into the `postad` table. How would I go about doing this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use an INSERT statement. (Or make your question more specific).

Comment: Not much we can do to help you without some more information.  What have you attempted?  What problems are you having?  Do you have any experience with SQL?

Comment: @shweta... Nice question, will tell you as soon as I figure out the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`INSERT` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx).

In general, one way to formulate your query is like this:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (columnlist) VALUES (valuelist);
```

You'd replace `tablename` with the name of the table you wish to insert into (in this case, `postad`). Also, you'd replace "`columnlist`" with the names of the columns you want to insert values into (separated by commas), and replace "`valuelist`" with the values that correspond to those columns (also separated by columns).

For example, to insert the values of `1` and `2` for `userid` and `cityid`, you'd do the following:

```
INSERT INTO postad (userid, cityid) VALUES (1, 2);
```

Comment: i am tryin to insert into postad table using c# coding n how should i insert

Comment: @shweta: create an stored procedure in the back-end and pass the value as parameters to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In sqlserver create procedure as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PSetPostAd
    (
    @userid  varchar(20),
    @cityid  varchar(20), 
    @Ucategory_id    varchar(20), 
    @ad_id   varchar(20), 
    @title   varchar(MAX),    
    @ad_description  varchar(MAX),   
    @img_id  int,
    @username    varchar(20), 
    @video  varchar(MAX),    
    @subcategory_id  varchar(50), 
    @date_creation   datetime,   
    @postid  int 
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT into postad(userid, cityid, Ucategory_id, ad_id, title, ad_description, img_id, ...) values
        (@userid, @cityid, ......)
    END
    GO
```

In your c# code do something like this:

```
SqlConnection cn;
public int saveData(string userid, string cityId, ......)
        {
            cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = getCommand();
            cmd.Parameters["@userid"].Value = userid;
            cmd.Parameters["@cityId"].Value = cityId;
            cmd.Parameters["@Ucategory_id"].Value = UCategory_id;
            //and so on
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }

        private SqlCommand getCategoryCommand()
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("PSetPostAd", cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@cityId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Ucategory_id", SqlDbType.Varchar, 20);
            //and so on
            return cmd;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two styles of using insert

```
Style 1: INSERT INTO PostAd(col1,col2,col3,col4...) VALUES (valforcol1,valforcol2,valforcol3..)

Style 2: INSERT INTO PostAd SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM <someothertable>
```

Considering your table :

```
userid  varchar(20) 
cityid  varchar(20) 
Ucategory_id    varchar(20) 
ad_id   varchar(20) 
title   varchar(MAX)    
ad_description  varchar(MAX)    
img_id  int username    varchar(20) 
 video  varchar(MAX)    
subcategory_id  varchar(50) 
date_creation   datetime    
postid  int
```

If you choose style1:

```
INSERT INTO PostAd (userid, cityid, Ucategory_id, ad_id,title,ad_description,img_id, username,video, subcategory_id,date_creation,postid)
VALUES (1,123,443,33,'My Ad','This is a great ad',123,'bradpitt','www.youtube.com/v=23e232',12,GETDATE(),1234)
```

Just make sure here that all the IDs e.g. userid, cityid, ucategory_id are valid ids and come from the master tables that you have created like category or adtype.

Style 2 is normally used when the data you want to insert in the current table has to come through a select query. The output of the select query is inserted as it is into the target table. One thing to make sure in using style 2 is that the output of the select query must contain exactly the same number of columns as the table in which you are trying to insert